# Using etag based caching on Couchdb / Cloudant views?

Tags: rest, http-headers, couchdb, etag, cloudant

I'm using Couchdb (hosted by Cloudant).  One of the cool things about Couchdb is that when you query a document, it supports standard http etag-based caching (the etag is the document's _rev field).

However, I notice that when I request a view, the etag is different on each request, even when the underlying documents haven't changed, which defeats the purpose of using etags to minimize traffic from the database server.

Is there a setting I need to tweak somewhere to fix this?

Edit:

Here's a link to my design document: 
https://codeliberate.cloudant.com/crowdfunder/_design/xLgxNgK_dXEQxHbzmEiCbWE_wackXLk83xDp28ShH8Q_

And here's link to the view output: https://codeliberate.cloudant.com/crowdfunder/_design/xLgxNgK_dXEQxHbzmEiCbWE_wackXLk83xDp28ShH8Q_/_view/xLgxNgK_dXEQxHbzmEiCbWE_wackXLk83xDp28ShH8Q_

Each time I refresh the view in Chrome and use the Network console to examine the headers sent by the server, I get a different etag (for instance, the last three times I refreshed I got 34c474c51f0beb87fa13755b9594c52a, 39da8a25e57ba660da6a905d8374b26f, and 6c5862d8d4a9375d484aaa1c1c9e8321 respectively).  Pretty sure the underlying data didn't change in between refreshes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, Cloudant supports ETag caching on individual documents (where the ETag is the document's `_rev` field), but not on views :(

Comment: Is this new, I remember couchdb having etags on views, and therefore lists. Is it a different implementation (I am on 2.0.0)?

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is quite surprising... As long as I don't change the documents, I get the same etag ever and ever for a view. And it works very well with the "If-None-Match" header.

Are you sure you use a "real view" and not:

- a temporary view?
- a list?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a real view.  I just edited the question to add a link to the view and the output.

Comment: Weird. I never saw that kind of problems. For now, my only hypothesis is that it could be related to implementation design choices specific to CloudAnt. To test this hypothesis, you should test your sample in a more standard Apache CouchDB implementation like [IrisCouch's](http://www.iriscouch.com/).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards Iris, hadn't looked at it.  I'll check it out.  Meanwhile, if anyone from Cloudant wants to weigh in...